# 404 error for a url on android that works on a PC

Tags: android

I have a problem with a url that returns a 404 on android 10 (in chrome or firefox for instance) but works on android 6 and on a PC. This url is http://tuntihinta.fi/json/errormessage.json I first thought that android denied non https traffic, however http://www.tuntihinta.fi/json/errormessage.json works just fine.

Here's the request generated in chrome. It works fine when executed in postman

```
curl 'http://tuntihinta.fi/json/errormessage.json' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Save-Data: on' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Nokia 7.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-XA;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

Any idea?

Comment: change **http** to **https**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However this is not possible at the moment. This server doesn't have a valid https certificate. But anyway this doesn't explain why one of the url works and not the other one.